# Как правильно отфильтровать два списка, которые связанными между собой полями по id в Dart/Flutter?

Tags: сортировка, flutter, dart, фильтрация

Я пытаюсь реализовать фильтрацию двух списков, используя id элемента. У меня есть 2 экрана. На первом экране: список по категориям: напитки, десерты, горячее, а на втором экране: элементы, которые принадлежат этим категориям. В документации и в других проектах видел, что просто в конструктор передают id. Однако у меня это не работает: на втором экране все также выводиться весь не отфильтрованный список

Я пробовал провести реализацию по методу where, передав его в параметр: `FoodSel(ttId: food.where((element) => element.ttId == 'ttId').toList()`, но все также выдается списком.

Как правильно отфильтровать значения и передать уже отфильтрованные значения на экран? уже все перепробовал включая методы `contains()` и `where()` вместе.

Думал над реализацией пузырьковой сортировки, но никак не могу понять, как правильно передать то, что насортировано в конструктор. (Да и нужна ли она вообще здесь?)

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Первый экран:

```
сlass FoodT extends StatelessWidget {
  List <Food> food = <Food>[
    Food(ttId: 1, ttTitle: 'Напитки'),
    Food(ttId: 2, ttTitle: 'Десерты'),
    Food(ttId: 3, ttTitle: 'Горячее'),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemCount: food.length,
          itemBuilder: (builder, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(food[index].ttTitle),
          subtitle: Text(food[index].ttId.toString()),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FoodSel(ttId: food[index].ttId)));
```

Второй экран:

```
List<FoodSelected> marsh = <FoodSelected>[
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Капучино",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Чизкейк",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Мясной стейк",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Американо",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Круассан",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Рыбный стейк",),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(itemCount: marsh.length,
              itemBuilder: (builder, index){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(marsh[index].mrTitle),
                  subtitle: Text(marsh[index].ttId.toString()),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо делать через переменную или get:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: FoodT(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Food {
  Food({this.ttId, this.ttTitle});

  final int ttId;
  final String ttTitle;
}

class FoodSelected {
  FoodSelected({this.ttId, this.mrTitle});

  final int ttId;
  final String mrTitle;
}

class FoodT extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Food> food = <Food>[
    Food(ttId: 1, ttTitle: 'Напитки'),
    Food(ttId: 2, ttTitle: 'Десерты'),
    Food(ttId: 3, ttTitle: 'Горячее'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: food.length,
      itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(food[index].ttTitle),
          subtitle: Text(food[index].ttId.toString()),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => FoodSel(ttId: food[index].ttId)));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FoodSel extends StatelessWidget {
  FoodSel({this.ttId});

  final int ttId;

  List<FoodSelected> marsh = <FoodSelected>[
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Капучино"),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Чизкейк"),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Мясной стейк"),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Американо"),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Круассан"),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Рыбный стейк"),
  ];

  List<FoodSelected> get marshViaId =>
      marsh.where((v) => v.ttId == ttId).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(ttId.toString())),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: marshViaId.length,
        itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(marshViaId[index].mrTitle),
            subtitle: Text(
              marshViaId[index].ttId.toString(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! @MiT Вы мне очень здорово помогли и спасли от еще одной бессонной ночи. Реально, затупил на этом моменте жестко.

Comment: @WildHaskyWhiskey ночью нужно спать! Ничего страшного, все через подобные моменты проходят. Ошибки для того и нужны, чтобы получить из них опыт)